Understanding the completed group algebra of a profinite ring.
I am learning about the completed group algebra $ k[[G]] = \underset{\underset{N\unlhd_{o}G}{\leftarrow}}{\lim} $ $k[\frac{G}{N}]$ of a profinite group $G$ and a finite field $k$.
As far as I understand, it should be fine to interpret this space as power series over $k$ with coefficients the elements of $G$. This is because if we think of the completed group algebra as the appropriate closed subalgebra of $\underset{N\unlhd_{o}G}{\prod}k[\frac{G}{N}]$, it is clear that we don't have any restrictions on the $\lambda_{g}$.
With this in mind I am having trouble realising the quotient maps from $k[[G]]$ to $k[\frac{G}{N}]$, defined by:$$ \underset{g\in G}{\Sigma}\lambda_{g}g \mapsto \underset{g\in G}{\Sigma}\lambda_{g}gN=\underset{gN\in \frac{G}{N}}{\Sigma}(\underset{\text{g' a representative of }  gN}{\Sigma}\lambda_{g'})gN $$.
I don't understand where an element like $\Sigma_{g\in G} 1g$ would map to, as there are infinite representatives of each coset in $\frac{G}{N}$, but infinite sums are not well-defined.
Am I missing something here? Am I completely wrong in thinking that power series over $k$ with coefficients the elements of the group is the same as this object?
Thanks a lot.


As far as I understand, it should be fine to interpret this space as power series over $k$ with coefficients the elements of $G$.

Actually it is not fine - there is no reason such power series should converge! As you yourself have said, there is no place for an element like $\sum_{g \in G} g$ to go in the finite quotients.
Here's an example that should hopefully clarify things. Let's look at the completed group ring for $G = \mathbb{Z}$, or equivalently for the profinite completion of $\mathbb{Z}$ (it doesn't matter much what the field $k$ is or that it's finite). This is the cofiltered (inverse) limit over the group algebras of the finite quotients $k[\mathbb{Z}/n] \cong k[x]/(x^n - 1)$, where $x$ is a generator of $\mathbb{Z}$. You are thinking the inverse limit should be the ring of formal power series $k[[x]]$, but this is incorrect - that's the cofiltered limit over the quotients $k[x]/x^n$, in which $x$ is nilpotent. Instead $x$ is always invertible.
The real limit is more complicated, but assuming for simplicity that $k$ is algebraically closed and characteristic zero, we have that $k[x]/(x^n - 1) \cong k^n$, a product of a copy of $k$ for every $n^{th}$ root of unity in $k$, and I believe but haven't checked carefully that this means the limit ends up being $\prod_{\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}} k$, a product of a copy of $k$ for every root of unity in $k$. (This $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is the Cartier dual of $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$ over $k$, or something like that.)
Intuitively speaking, in the completed group algebra you want to think of the elements $g \in G$ not as being infinitesimal (like the $x$ in the ring of formal power series $k[[x]]$ is) but as being infinitesimally close to the identity (like the elements of a Lie algebra are in relation to a Lie group). So you want to think not in terms of power series of the form $\sum_g \lambda_g g$ but in terms of power series of the form $\sum_g \lambda_g (g - e)$, funnily enough. And then there's a clear criterion for convergence: in any finite quotient $G/N$, all but finitely many of the nonzero terms $\lambda_g$ should vanish (that is, we should have $g \in N$). This is precisely the condition needed to write down a meaningful element of $k[G/N]$ that evaluates to a finite, non-formal sum.
It's not obvious that there are any nontrivial infinite such series but, for example, when $G = \mathbb{Z}$, the power series $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (x^{n!} - 1)$ converges, because in a given finite quotient $\mathbb{Z}/d$ all but finitely many factorials are divisible by $d$, and so all but finitely many terms vanish. When $k$ is algebraically closed the image of this power series in the copy of $k$ corresponding to a given root of unity $\zeta$ is $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (\zeta^{n!} - 1)$.

Add a screen shot

I apologise because I realise that my question is almost a grammar one (as in English grammar), but when you say in any finite quotient $\frac{G}{N}$, all but finitely many of the nonzero terms should vanish, or in other words, a finite amount of representatives of any coset other than $eN$ can be non-zero. Is this a condition you are imposing? If it is, since we need this condition to be imposed for every open normal subgroup of $G$ and since the open normal subgroups form a poset, aren't we saying we can only allow finitely many coefficients to be non-zero?

P.S: As for the Latex issues, it is very plausible that I am just typing poorly. Please let me know if you are having this issue only with my post, so that I can retype it.

@Facundo: yes, that's the condition we need to impose for the series to converge, sorry for my language being unclear. And the last sentence of the answer provides an example of a series with infinitely many terms having this property. The LaTeX issues were on my end and I found a fix, no worries.

@QiaochuYuan Oh I see! Now I understand your example. This has been very helpful. Thanks a lot.

@Facundo: you're very welcome! I've edited in a bit more explanation to help anyone else looking at this.

@QiaochuYuan Hey, I have thought about this a little more and I think your condition is too restrictive. There might be more elements here. Take for example $s=(\Sigma_{i\in\mathbb{N}}(x^{p^{i}}-1)$ in $k[[\mathbb{Z}{p}]]$ (borrowing your example but in the p-adics). This is a well-defined element by the reasons you mention, but the element $x\cdot s=\Sigma{i\in\mathbb{N}}(x^{p^{i+1}}-1)-(x-1)$ should also be an element in $k[[\mathbb{Z}{p}]]$, since $k[[\mathbb{Z}{p}]]$ is a $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$-module.

Also, and more explicitily, x\cdot s corresponds to the fitting element $(\Sigma_{i=1}^{n}(x^{p^{i}+1}-1) - n(x-1)){n\in\mathbb{N}} \in \Pi{i\in \mathbb{N}}k[\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}}]$.

@Facundo: ah, yes, I didn't mean to imply that this was all elements, just that if you wanted to think in terms of power series indexed by $G$ this was the obvious sufficient criterion for convergence.
